# How can I use certain LinkedIn APIs?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

My company is creating a web application and we're using LinkedIn APIs. However, we can't figure out how to allow LinkedIn users to send LinkedIn invite requests, LinkedIn user-to-user messages, and LinkedIn view profile actions within our web-based dashboard.

We're looking for what APIs we should be using (or if there is another way) and/or how to get access to those APIs. Below is a link to a company that is currently able to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of a company doing what we're trying to do: https://skylead.io/solution/linkedin-automation/

We tried reaching our to LinkedIn (multiple ways, researching online, etc.). We were expecting to have access to these APIs for our application without it being this tough to figure out.

Comment: if these APIs are not documented and support is not helping you on this matter, this must mean the APIs either do not exist or are not available to general public. You can try emulating user's browser, but I'm willing to bet this is against LinkedIn's ToS.